# Setting GPO security filter with powershell Set-GPPermissions cmdlet

Tags: security, powershell, filter, powershell-cmdlet, gpo

According to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461038.aspx) the cmdlet [Set-GPPermissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461038.aspx) accepts the option "-replace":

> "This ensures that the existing permission level is replaced by the new permission level."

I import a GPO from PowerShell. After that I want to set the security filters. After importing, before setting the security filter, the Security Filtering of the GPO is "Authenticated Users". Now I want to remove that filter option and replace it with "myGroup". To do so I use the following command:

```
Set-GPPermissions -Name "myGPO" -PermissionLevel GpoApply -TargetName "myGroup" -TargetType Group -replace
```

The results are that there is a new security filter added which references "myGroup", but the Group "Authenticated Users" is not being removed. The Powershell cmdlet is not *replacing* the filter, it's *adding* it.

Hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

As documented on the page you referenced, the command would replace already existing `permissions` of a group "myGroup". It won't replace permissions for a group "Authenticated Users" with permissions for a group "myGroup". Quoting from [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461038.aspx):

> -Replace < SwitchParameter >
>
> Specifies that the existing permission level for the group or user is removed before the new permission level is set.

You'll have to use `Set-GPPermissions` to grant permissions to "myGroup" and `Set-GPPermissions -TargetName "Authenticated Users -PermissionLevel None` to remove permissions for "Authenticated Users".

Answer (score 2):

I found that it's sufficient to set the Authenticated User permissionlevel to none like this:

```
Set-GPPermissions -Name "MyGPO" -PermissionLevel None -TargetName "Authenticated Users" -TargetType Group
```

That removed the "Authenticated Users" security filter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have accepted Ansgar's or user1458620's answer; they're correct.
Here is a final solution incorporating the same:

```
$gpo | Set-GPPermissions -Replace -PermissionLevel None -TargetName 'Authenticated Users' -TargetType group 
$gpo | Set-GPPermissions -PermissionLevel gpoapply -TargetName 'MyGroup' -TargetType group
```

Comment: If you are getting a confirmation prompt and want to get rid of it, use `dsacls` instead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60371989/11942268).