# How to execute Set-GPPermissions command without confirmation prompt

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, gpo

```
Set-GPPermissions -Guid <Guid> -TargetName "Authenticated Users" -PermissionLevel None -TargetType Group -Replace -Confirm:$false
```

Used to work fine, but when KB3163622 patch was installed it now asks me confirmation prompt:

> "Group Policy requires each computer account to have permission to read GPO data from a domain controller in order for
>   User Group Policy settings to be successfully applied. Removing the Authenticated Users group may prevent processing of
>    User Group Policies. For more information, please see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3163622
>   Do you want to continue ?"

I execute this command from Powershell and C#.

There is any way to skip this confirmation prompt?

Comment: I've never seen `-Confirm:$false` fail before... You're running it from an administrative account?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Confirmation prompt appears in both cases.

Comment: `-Confirm:$false` suppress confirmation prompt before command execution. My confirmation prompt appears during command execution.

Comment: Although you should definitely change this back after testing, try setting the `$ConfirmPreference` to "none" `$ConfirmPreference = "none"` . The default is "high"

Comment: I tried to set `$ConfirmPreference = "none"`. It doesn't work.

Comment: Ditto Nick. Could it be worth asking this on the Server Fault forum, especially if you suspect this isn't an issue with PowerShell and might be a change in behaviour of the cmdlet?

Comment: @CharlieJoynt, Agreed. Andrei, have you tried running it on a different machine with the patch to see if you get the same error? Until you figure it out, just run it on one that doesn't need or doesn't have that patch.

Comment: It works fine on the different machine with the same patch. Strange.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Set-GPPermission`, you can use the built-in tool `dsacls`, that does not prompt for confirmation:

```
dsacls "cn={$($gpo.id)},cn=policies,$((Get-ADDomain).SystemsContainer)" /R "Authenticated Users"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked on a different machine, check the PowerShell version. If they are not the same, get the non-working machine on the same version. If that doesn't work, I'd recommend uninstalling and reinstalling the patch. Finally, if you're still having issues, take an inventory of both machines to see what is different on them. Software, .NET version, etc.

If that still doesn't work, it would seem that something is corrupt or misconfigured on the bad machine. If you can figure out what it is, then fix it. Otherwise, just use the other one if you can, or re-image the non-working machine.